# I cannot translate the action label

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm using Umami profile and choose Spanish is default language. Almost of the interface has been translated into Spanish. But some places did not translate like user page.

[image]

I'm going to **admin/config/regional/translate** to check. But This text already translated, but UI still show English text.

[image]
I try debug to find the reason. I was break point at line 340 of line drupal/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/BulkForm.php and found that $action->label() return English string.

[image]

Because at line 116 `$this->actionStorage->loadMultiple()` return all actions. In this some actions return English string, some actions return Spanish string (example install module pathauto, this action return Spanish). All actions when install profile will using English text and module install after will be translate.

[image]

I don't know why. And How to can translate label of actions?

Answer (score 5):

To translate action labels install the core module **Actions** and go to `/admin/config/regional/config-translation/action`.

Actions are config entities, which you can translate in an exported config as well, if you don't want to install the UI option.

Comment: Thank you for support. Do you why all core config entities did not translate? But config entities from other modules (install after default) will be translated.

Comment: When the config entities are created on installation they are parsed through user interface translation. There might be a timing issue downloading translations and creating those entities. But I think installing the Actions module is the way to go if you want to correct this after installation.

Comment: It appears that you can uninstall the Actions module after doing the translations. At least, I've not run into any bugs so far, and the translations are still there. I'll come back if I discover otherwise.

Comment: Yes, Action configuration is part of the system module and is not affected by uninstalling the Actions UI module.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate them easily in `hook_form_alter()`.

```php
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id ='views_exposed_form' && isset($form['header']['node_bulk_form']['action']['#options'])) {
    foreach ($form['header']['node_bulk_form']['action']['#options'] as $key => $option) {
      $form['header']['node_bulk_form']['action']['#options'][$key] = t($option);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The "You should never use t() to translate variables" doesn't count anymore for D8? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x

Comment: @leymannx I've tested it before and works.

Comment: @YusefMohamadi thank you for support. But I think this way does not good. Because It's not convenient. Suppose we have 20 roles, so we need to translate 40 strings (add+remove roles). And this ways does not resolved root of cause. When you load all config entity action why  some actions install after finish install profile will return string translated?

Comment: @Jonh you're welcome, if it has been translated on the core it shows the translated text else it's the core issue. btw,  this is a convenient solution and 100% works. I've tested it. hope to find a better solution but it's really very hard to achieve it without patching the core or this convenient solution.

Comment: Variables should not be passed through the t() function. It may work, but it can open up security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Jaypan what security vulnerability? would you  please add more details

Comment: From the documentation: `It is especially important never to call new TranslatableMarkup($user_text) or t($user_text) where $user_text is some text that a user entered -- doing that can lead to cross-site scripting and other security problems.` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/function/TranslatableMarkup%3A%3A__construct/8.7.x

Comment: @Jaypan but in this case, we are not facing user-entered texts, the are modules texts. if they contain XSS js, they can be harmful  in their own. do not need this . I mean  these texts are not user entered texts.

btw, if you are concern about the text  and xss, you can easily add a 'check_plain'

So it would be `t(check_plain($option));`

Comment: Ok. Then you only have the other reasons to not pass variables through t() and not that one.

Comment: @Jaypan sorry, I didn't get your reply.  that's true some times letting the user to pass text through t() function can be harmful but it does not mean it is harmful in any way.

Comment: Well, the security reason is only one reason not to use variables in the t() function. See the documentation page I linked to above. If you want to pass variables through t(), that's your choice, but it's considered a bad practice.

Comment: @Jaypan So, what is that for ? :)

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/function/TranslatableMarkup%3A%3A__construct/8.7.x

Comment: @Jaypan **At run-time it translates user-visible text into the appropriate language.**

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking/saying.